# PHP Fatal error: require(): unable to unlock pthread lock

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I'm using LAMP on Debian Linux. Apache 2.2.22-12, PHP 5.4.4.

Sometimes I get this error and then i couldn't reload page or open pages, which includes file with this error. After I've got such error i couldn't restart apache

> Restarting web server: apache2(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>
> (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down
>
> Unable to open logs
>
> Action 'start' failed.
>
> The Apache error log may have more information.
>    failed!

In apache log file:

> [Wed Nov 21 15:07:55 2012] [warn] child process 4020 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
>
> [Wed Nov 21 15:07:55 2012] [warn] child process 4021 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
>
> [Wed Nov 21 15:07:55 2012] [warn] child process 4022 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
>
> [Wed Nov 21 15:07:57 2012] [error] child process 1309 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
>
> [Wed Nov 21 15:07:57 2012] [error] child process 1310 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
>
> [Wed Nov 21 15:07:57 2012] [error] child process 1311 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL

And host log:

> [Wed Nov 21 12:21:24 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require(): unable to unlock pthread lock in ~/www/yii/yii-1.1.11.58da45/framework/base/CApplication.php on line 127

There is

```
$config=require($config);
```

Or:

> [Wed Nov 14 21:04:26 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): unable to unlock pthread lock in ~/projects/politiya/index.php on line 14

There is:

```
require_once($game_loader);
```

---

I've deleted php-apc and now lamp works good.

Comment: something's locking up an apache child, preventing it from exiting, and preventing apache from being able to restart/rebind to port 80, because that child from the previous instance is still bound. without any code, we cannot help you.

Comment: the error could links to any line with php-require

Comment: `define("GAME_PATH", dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'game');
define("ENGINE_PATH", dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'engine');

$config = ENGINE_PATH . '/config/game.php';
$game_loader = ENGINE_PATH . '/loader.php';`

Comment: looks like something related to apc. your exact error message shows up here: http://www.uni-jena.de/bin/tool/APC/APC/apc_pthreadmutex.c

Comment: so, the only way to start apache after this error is to restart all system, that's not very good

Comment: at least restart apache and apc. probably doesn't need a full system reboot.

Comment: no, when i'm restarting apache `Restarting web server: apache2(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down

Unable to open logs

Action 'start' failed.

The Apache error log may have more information. failed!`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Fix

As mentioned [here](http://codedmemes.com/lib/php-performance-apc-os-x-server/), I had to quickly uninstall and reinstall apc (literaly takes 5s):

<kbd>1</kbd> `sudo pecl uninstall apc`

<kbd>2</kbd> `sudo pecl install apc`

`BUT` change the **`no`** which is already filled in for pthread mutexes into a **`yes`**

`AND` change the **`yes`** which is already filled in for pthread read/write locks into a **`no`**.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for APC 3.1.13 well. I had a lot of deadlocks before, I have none now.

Answer (score 5):

This error happens because of a 'deadlock bug' in APC.
A [php bug report page](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59620) says that, this bug is fixed in APC 3.1.8

Also we can see the APC change logs [here](http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=APC)

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI (in response to OMG's comment about APC version bug), I'm running APC 3.1.13 and PHP 5.4.17 and I still got the bug:

```
unable to obtain pthread lock (EDEADLK)
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this is fixable for APC 3.1.13, see answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496165/php-fatal-error-require-unable-to-unlock-pthread-lock/22085259#22085259#answer-22085259)

Answer (score -1):

This ,means some process ir running which is using this port so try to kill that process

like get the process

eg : ps -ef | grep httpd

then kill the process

eg kill -9 process ID

-----------------------OR----------------------

port 80 is utilised by another service, so locate and change system-config-httpd.conf: system-config-httpd.conf system-config-httpd.conf. all of this, restart httpd:
/etc/init.d/httpd start