# Error while loading the debug toolbar / unable to obtain pthread lock | Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Almost each time I want to see a page of my website with app_dev.php, I get the dialog box "An error occured while loading the debug toolbar" and if I click with Firefug to see the details I get this error :

> FatalErrorException: Error: require() [function.require]: unable to
>   obtain pthread lock (EDEADLK) in
>   /Users/me/Sites/myproject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php
>   line 120

This is really annoying ...

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: I cannot offer a specific answer but I've come across this - I'm pretty sure it's related to an APC issue/bug.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496165/php-fatal-error-require-unable-to-unlock-pthread-lock

Answer (score 0):

It definitely is related to APC, that's the only thing emitting that error.

http://lxr.php.net/xref/PECL/APC/apc_pthreadmutex.c#76

(the rwlock can emit the same error)

Two things:

- The message could be wrong; depending upon the default mutex attributes of your operating system, EDEADLK can mean that you already hold the lock, not that you cannot acquire it
- There is not much we can do about it ...

APC supports many different kinds of locking, because of this, and because of the various return values given by each implementation to signify different locking states, APC's codebase does not check the return value of calls to locking functions, other than to completely bail within the locking function itself, as you are seeing. The business logic though is unable to prepare for strange states, like EDEADLK ...

It would be my guess, and I'm probably right, that something somewhere is doing something that leads to attempting to recursively lock the cache, likely that this is due to calls to include/require/autoloaders rather than calls to acquire data from the user cache.

None of the things I'm saying really help ... sorry about that ...